# iOS - member reference is a pointer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to assign a AVAudioPlayer to a property using this

```
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"error"
                                          withExtension:@"aiff"];
AVAudioPlayer *avSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
           initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
self.soundError = avSound;
```

I am receiving an error on the last line saying: **member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer; maybe you meant use '->' ?**

the property is declared like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *soundError;
```

pointer? I don't get it.

thanks

Comment: `AVAudioPlayer *soundError;` <-- so it's a pointer.

Comment: avSound is always a points, so? what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You did not post your full method but the error may indicate that you're trying to assign property in the class method, not in an instance method.

Check if your method declaration is correct - probably it should be

```
- (void) someMethod
```

instead of

```
+ (void) someMethod
```

Comment: ah, sorry about that. Thanks for pointing that out. Problem solved!

Comment: @RubberDuck, if you really need that method to be class method and make soundError shared between all instances you can make soundError global (may be static) variable in that file. Or you can use your class as a singleton if that suits your application design

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I am doing after you pointed out the problem... 

Answer (score 0):

To use dot notation you need the getter/setter methods. 
If you do not provide your own methods, use

```
@synthesize soundError;
```

Otherwise, use `self->soundError` to set the ivar.